# PHPSECLIB Javascript compatibility

Tags: javascript, php, rsa, phpseclib

i've followed [this guide](http://bestmike007.com/2011/08/secure-data-transmission-between-pure-php-and-javascript-using-rsa/) to implement RSA on my website and all work fine. 
encrypt in RSA in Javascript and decrypt in PHP...but the problem is how to encrypt in PHP and decrypt in PHP with this configuration. 
i'LL show you my code, i need help.
thanks in advance.

THIS IS MY CODE:

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-rsa/jsbn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-rsa/prng4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-rsa/rng.js"></script>
<script src="js-rsa/rsa.js"></script>
function rsajsencrypt(data){
var rsa = new RSAKey();
rsa.setPublic('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', '010001');
var crypted = rsa.encrypt(data);
return(crypted);
}
```

and this is how i decrypt with PHP. IT WORKS FINE.

```
  $pvKey =  file_get_contents("key.txt");
  $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
  $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
  $rsa->loadKey($pvKey, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1);
  $s = new Math_BigInteger($hidden_key, 16);
  $showed_key = $rsa->decrypt($s->toBytes());
```

so...the following is the PHP FUNCTION to encrypt in RSA and that DON't let me ENCRYPT something that i can decrypt in php.
TO USE Javascript to encrypt i have to generate the $newpbkey that encrypts in Js, but don't seems to work in php (the old ones works with php but not with js...help...) i know that they are different type and i think that this is the problem but i don't know how to solve.

```
 function rsaencryptphp($data){
   require_once("Crypt/RSA.php");
/*$oldpbKey = "MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA6XkN3syXRnmj+NX2JMsM fZQh2kkHHaqprQQ8yxYF2GJRMHPFmEWwjhPf385px6eVhQ2xZTmVSzRerxNTNLNg 3FPeC53c27acG5lBBkJkVGiQaPUqvdcSwz/zeVnXJnQeoDPTxGKd4pCHTLfiCNEE pnwaCflsOd3Crp5/bHcKjE97AlTmyyssO8bY16a5DFK+zuFnoid0nit4Q89LYdNa m5yGGfetkc2YWDEwsMcVYnEnHJ4A2gdLPctwY0sngvBguXlwMi4orKVMotsRgKAW Vg5wTlNYGEoWrwXIUIjIVa8Ao9KBRrIJIkOEUXnMcAk23bGIZDJUAdSMWTjFMzQ2 cDN4Qkw6YBOOv6aGCyew47voiHlkyOKXkK+Tnze5cxTHN5pP4ZZOz8RKkkDBL+bt Mpe3vt8pJvzIYynegrCJ8URa1wtc8zY+SiueO32rcHug/WI37ZI1JI/PvHb3HzhK o00stgW2eJyWplglbZ4ds+s+7M/GWdfUc6ytM0qd6B3fyXXD9dsZMwIqwFVduv1q BUoAYaihuEoimubRRrKqCQKpugFO0b7B9O4ukE55JlvpBfIAytIcYm/ID7CVIPYN S2OOf5LhuydorSymwKfTtZPe18RFVfyd19ggclV6jA9BwqOkyfmwD3IYdWwNbEYH rULzEB0U3QLHGwZ85fVUTSECAwEAAQ==";*/
$newpbKey = "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";
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($pbKey); // public key
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($data);
return $ciphertext;
 }
```

info: phpseclib is the rsa library that i'm using

Comment: If you aren't already using SSL, this doesn't add any security.  If you are using SSL, there is no point.

Comment: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: You're just reinventing the wheel here. SSL already does this, more strongly, faster, gracefully, and throughout your entire site. Just use that!

Comment: anyway SSL don't save encrypted data in my DB, so i think i have a compatible variable in some programming / scripting languages...i choose to use javascript and php.

Comment: The precedent comment is direct to @ConnorPeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution on my own, i share it down here.
Thanks to everyone have tried help me.

### Joshua Bane

```
function rsaencrypt($plaintext){
require_once("Crypt/RSA.php");
$pbKey = "082c1d7fb252ba5de3b0342d634d54b50ceea07decd760bc60cef2e1b5918a10c21349cca1539acf4cb4e39b5605ab31c8073e1b5bb9a78cf38f42c90f0c119f39d42829a8f25aa9bc13d842a53eda75ddbc7d212bfb0c1fce8c7ea8402554f311e7a67002a4d588653361354685d2b02c73ed708";
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$public_key = array(
 'n' => new Math_BigInteger($pbKey, 16),
 'e' => new Math_BigInteger('65537', 10) // same value as function that create KEY
           );
$rsa->loadKey($public_key,CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
$ciphertext_hex = bin2hex($ciphertext);
return $ciphertext_hex;
}
```